# URLs with no prefixes

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I wonder if it is possible to access all pages and its detail pages without any extra prefix.

Example:

```
'''
/vegetables
/carrot -->  (detail page for vegetables)
/fruits
/apple  -->  (detail page for fruits)
'''
```

Sample URL patterns and I add the views on request.

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('fruits/', views.all_fruits, name='fruits'),
    path('vegetables/', views.all_vegetables, name='vegetables'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.fruit_detail, name='fruit'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.vegatable_detail, name='vegetable'),
    ]

#views.py
    from .models import Fruit, Vegetable
    def index(request):
        return render (request, 'index.html')
    
    def all_fruits(request):
        fruits=Fruit.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'fruits.html', {'fruits':fruits})
    
    def all_vegetables(request):
        vegetables=Vegetable.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'vegetables.html', {'vegetables':vegetables})
    
    def fruit_detail (request, slug):
        fruit = get_object_or_404(Fruit, slug=slug)
        return render(request, 'fruit_detail.html', {'fruit':fruit})
    
    def vegetable_detail (request, slug):
        vegetable = get_object_or_404(Vegetable, slug=slug)
        return render(request, 'vegetable_detail.html', {'vegetable':vegetable})
```

Predictably;  when trying to access the vegetable detail page, gives an error because of using fruit's views.

Thanks in advance for your help and feedback.

Comment: show your views please

Comment: @AndreyBorzenko I added the views.

Comment: I posted a rather long answer which is not exactly a code answer to your question but advice for new Django develeoper. If you really what the answer to your question **which I do not recommend** I can also post it

Comment: @quqa123 Your suggestions and explanations are very valuable, i appreciate that. Also, I am aware that is inefficient to display the detail pages without prefix but  I want to experience this so I would be glad if you can also post the answer to the question.

Comment: please upvote the answer if you find it helpful so others can also use it as a valid learning source

Comment: @quqa123 I already upvoted the answer but because of my reputation is less than 15,  my votes don't publicly display as post score.

Comment: thanks, please rethink the design - if its only for training its okay but if its for a real life app, you will sooner o later see the downsides of such solution - ie. coutnless hits in whole Fruits table if the query is a Vegetable and many more like hard refactoring and unscalability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are trying to achieve is possible by writting special redirecting view when you look for particular slug firstly in `Fruit` objects and then in `Vegetable` objects and add found instance to template context **but** it is highly inefficient and "dirty". Using standard urls (as you do now) the Django router will not know which `slug` you are refering to when someone enters for example `yoursite.com/xyzabc` Django doesnt know if it should look for instance by slug in `fruit` table or `vegetable` table. 
You should continue creating your problem as you do now but I propose you using (in my opinion) more mature solution using Django's [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/). Of course you can use them without deep understanding of [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/) but I strongly recommend you using them.

#### intro

As you probably notices you used the "same" copy/paste code for all your function based views. It's okay nothing wrong with that on a small project **but** you should always want to make your code flexible, scalable and more importantly easy to refactor/reformat

#### [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

is useful when most of your view focuses on rendering a list of objects like your `all_fruits` and `all_vegetables`

#### [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)

is useful when you want to display template with your particular instance's info. That's exactly what you do in your `fruit_detail` and `vegetable_detail`

*Your code but written in CBV*
**views.py**

```
    from .models import Fruit, Vegetable
    from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
    from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
    from django.views.generic.list import ListView

    class IndexView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'index.html'
    
    # former all_fruits view
    class FruitListView(ListView):
        model = Fruit
        template_name = 'fruits.html'
  
    class VegetableListView(ListView):
        model = Vegetable
        template_name = 'vegetables.html'

    # former fruit_detail view
    class FruitDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Fruit
        template_name = 'fruit_detail.html'

    class VegetableDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Vegetable
        template_name = 'vegetable_detail.html'
```

if you look closely into generic views you'd notice you can even skip the `template_name` part if you build your project tree accordingly to Django's docs

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('fruits/', views.FruitListView.as_view(), name='fruits'),
    path('vegetables/', views.VegetableListView.as_view(), name='vegetables'),
    path('fruits/<slug:slug>/', views.FruitDetailView.as_view(), name='fruit'),
    path('vegetables/<slug:slug>/', views.VegetableDetailView.as_view(), name='vegetable'),
    ]
```

The above anwser shows how it should be done following best Django practices but as we know sometimes clients have special needs for example because of CEO reasons so in order to fully anwser the question here is how to access detail page of multiple models using one route (url).

**views.py**

```
# instead of using two views VegetableDetailView and FruitDetalView 
# we will use one common view to filter out the needed instance
# Rest of the code stays as in upper answer

...

class FruitOrVegetableDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs)
        try:
            return render(request, 'fruit_detail.html', 
                    {'fruit': Fruit.objects.get(slug=slug)})
        except Fruit.DoesNotExist:
            veg = get_object_or_404(Vegetable, slug=slug)
            return render(request, 'vegetable_detail.html', 
                    {'vegetable': veg})
```

of course we need to change routing

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('fruits/', views.FruitListView.as_view(), name='fruits'),
    path('vegetables/', views.VegetableListView.as_view(), name='vegetables'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.FruitOrVegetableDetailView.as_view(), name='fruit_or_vegetable_detail'),
    ]
```